# How to find unique fields in raw data

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-analysis

I don't expect a code solution, but a tip or idea.

I have a log of 1,000,000 messages. I know the timestamp, the message id and the payload (8 bytes). Each set of messages with the same ID is built in the same structure.

Are there any good algorithms or ways to analyze each message to find its unique structure, and maybe get a profile of this field (incremental, linear, constant, etc).

I understand it's not a simple task, but what is the general direction?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) first.

Comment: I believe the question falls under the algorithm topic.